# Flutter: change dark mode switch to an Icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented dark mode for my flutter project which is switched on/off using Swich placed in the Drawer, as you can see the following code:

```
final themeChange = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);

ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.brightness_2, size: 30.0, color: Colors.blue),
              title: Text('night mode', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
              trailing: Switch(
                value: themeChange.darkTheme,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  themeChange.darkTheme = value;
                },
              ),
            ),
```

This is the class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:azkar/core/shared/sharedpreferances.dart';

class DarkThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DarkThemePreference darkThemePreference = DarkThemePreference();
  bool _darkTheme = false;

  bool get darkTheme => _darkTheme;

  set darkTheme(bool value) {
    _darkTheme = value;
    darkThemePreference.setDarkTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The situation I am facing now is that some of the screens dose not have Drawer. Therefore, I wanted to be able to on/off the dark mode from the app bar of these screens, as you know putting switch in the app bar does not look good. How can I put an icon to do that, where the icon will change to another icon when it is on and back to the  org. icon when change to off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the answer as follows:

First add this variable:

```
  var _icon = Icons.wb_sunny;
```

Then implement this code to change the icon and also switch the function between the dark mode and the light mode:

```
IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              _icon,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_icon == Icons.wb_sunny) {
                  _icon = Icons.brightness_2;
                  themeChange.darkTheme = true;
                } else {
                  _icon = Icons.wb_sunny;
                  themeChange.darkTheme = false;
                }
              });
            },
          ),
```